# Windows Server 2012 Standard - Windows Store?

Tags: windows

Pretty simple question really... how (if it's at all possible) do you get the Windows Store on Windows Server 2012?

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've figured this one out now. Just in-case anyone else is curious:

On your server manager click 'Add roles and features'. When the wizard pops up just follow the wizard until you get to the 'Features' section. From there scroll down in the list of features to down near the bottom and expand the 'User Interfaces and Infrastructure' section, tick the 'Desktop Experience' checkbox and and click next.

It'll probably ask you to install a bunch of other things with it. Say yes, then boom! You have desktop experience. That's not all yet though, you'll be able to see the store on your start screen now but you'll have to create a user that isn't the main administrator to actually use the windows store, i.e. you can make another administrator user and use that instead and it'll work just fine.

Comment: Never would have thought to look there. Looked past that @$#%er more than a few times.